# Can it be dangerous to give access to user output in img src

Tags: php, html, security

here is the situation. I'm building a small site and no file is confidential in it. In many pages, I needed to isolate and print an image for the user. So, I made a small script this way:

```
<?php
    echo '<img src="'. $_GET['src'] .'" />';
?>
```

And I like the image source in the URL so it's easy for me to reuse. I am wondering if somebody could try to access other file in the server (for example `mysite.com?src=../../SECRET_FILE.txt`). I tried to break it myself and couldn't do anything dangerous with this but I'm wondering if it has any flaw? (In the perspective that no image is secret in this website, they are all public and it wouldn't bother me at all if they would find any of these)

Note that the code is not saved in anyway, here is the full script of this page (really just used to save time for user that wants to print an image on the website)

```
<?php
    echo '<img src="'. $_GET['src'] .'" />';
?>
<script>
    window.print();
</script>
```

Comment: A must-read for you (and anyone else you doesn’t immediately realize how dangerous the code as shown is): https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)

Comment: @CBroe even if it is not saved in any database? It just echo the $_GET value into a img src and then it runs a javascript print. In this condition can it be dangerous?

Comment: Of course, because I could send a link including such a GET parameter to other people, and then get my JS executed, that can do all sorts of things … redirect them to a malware site, possibly steal their cookies, …

Comment: And sould you have any kind of “admin” actions available on the page (like a form to delete something from the database), and it lacks proper CSRF protection as well, then I could execute those as well, if I send _you_ such a link. And before you say, _“yeah, but I’ll notice when I see a URL with such parameters”_ – no, you probably won’t, not until it is too late, if I send you an “innocent” looking URL that _redirects_ to your site with the malicious parameter, f.e. via a URL shortener service …

Comment: @CBroe It's very logic and nice to know, I do alot of security on websites I have that has admin sections but never tought something so simple could be so easily exploited you are right, I will do some validation to make sure that the URL is safe. Thanks alot for the explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never trust user input.  If every file or script you expose is safe to run, there is no danger of unsafe server-side code running.  But you're allowing users to alter your HTML in any way they desire, which is unsafe.

I would check they enter something valid, such as:

```
echo '<img src="/path/to/images/'. basename($_GET['src']) .'" />';
```

This will confirm they are only requesting a file from your images directory. Even better would be to confirm the file exists:

```
$image = '/path/to/images/' . basename($_GET['src']);
if (file_exists($image)) {
     echo '<img src="'. $image .'" />';
} else {
     header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's safe server side wise, but your users could use a cross site scripting attack to inject html in it. Think of inserting an script tag to send your site's cookie to the attacker website.

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_Cross_site_scripting

Comment: yes but the script is not saved in a database, it really just echo the img in a page and in javascript, then, print it. So the XSS would not be saved anywhere. Could it still be a flaw in those conditions?

Comment: @YannChabot XSS can occur when a user is sent to your site with a GET parameter you don't validate.  It doesn't need to be saved on your server, just allowing a user to request it is unsafe.

Comment: Oh I understand what you mean and how now, it's clear to me. I will validate that the values are what I expect. Thank you @MattS

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to be extremely careful when implementing such methods. In this case I would change the implementation to

1. Check the input to be in a valid/allowed range: store the filenames of allowed images in an array. Work with indices into that array as user parameters. Indices are very easily checked and validated. Thus, no external user can access images he is not allowed to access.
2. Check the argument to be (1.) numeric and (2.) within the allowed range (0 - array length-1)

I strongly recommend to never ever implement functionality that enables users to scan server directories.